# Capture error message from compiled PHP file

Tags: php, command-line

I'm using [top2ec](http://www.thinkitbetter.com/thinkitbetter-joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=132%3Atop2ecv037-the-other-php-2-exe-compiler&catid=96%3Aprogramming&lang=en) to compile a PHP script and making an executable file of it, so I can distribute the file. Since this application will only run a few times to capture some data, I've used PHP enabling me to create an application without learning a new language.

Everything works fine, but the application runs on the commandline and this gets closed everytime it run in an error. To be able to debug I need to capture the error information. Does anyone know a way to get this information?

I've been looking at STDERR, but I can't really understand how it would work within the application as I don't call any other software.

So the question is basically: **How to capture error messages from my top2ec compiled commandline script?**

All tips are much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What operating system are you using? The methods for capturing stderr tend to differ.

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning, I'm on Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to define your own error handling function. You can use it to (for example) write any error messages to a text file.